# How to make tableViewCell handle both tap and longPress?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uigesturerecognizer

I put this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CalorieCountViewController.handleLongPress))
cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
longPress.cancelsTouchesInView = true
let tapPress = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CalorieCountViewController.handleTapPress))
cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapPress)
tapPress.cancelsTouchesInView = true
```

and put these(code below) outside of it, and removed didSelectRowAtIndexPath function entirely, use indexPathForSelectedRow instead to get which row user just selected.

```
func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    doSomething(index)
}

func handleTapPress(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    doSomethingElse(index)
}
```

Turns out indexPathForSelectedRow returns nil, but I did select a row, and there is no "deselectRowAtIndexPath" anywhere in my code.

Comment: only add long press gesture on UITableViewCell and for tap you can use "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" delegate method of UITableView

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Don't add the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to `Cell`. Add it to `UITableView` in `viewDidLoad`

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(sender:)))
tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

Get the touched cell index by

```
@objc private func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began {
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            // your code here, get the row for the indexPath or do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of `UITapGestureRecognizer` use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is a better way

Comment: And what might be longPressGestureRecognizer? You should change the name of parameter in your method

Answer (score 6):

Update Swift4:

Add these lines in `viewDidLoad` of your viewController class (in this example class's name is `YourViewController`)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
}
```

Now add this `func` in your viewController class

```
@objc func longPress(longPressGestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if longPressGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            // add your code here
            // you can use 'indexPath' to find out which row is selected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually will show the wrong indexPath. You need to add the gestureRecognizer to the tableView in `viewDidLoad`, not the view. Replace `self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)` with `tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)`. Also, change `let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)` to be `let touchPoint = longPressGestureRecognizer.location(in: tableView)`.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Bala Answer here is on swift 4 or 5

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longpress))
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }
```

Here is the method

```
@objc func longPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

            if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
                let touchPoint = sender.location(in: tableView)
                if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
                    // your code here, get the row for the indexPath or do whatever you want
                    print("Long press Pressed:)")
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Suggestion to change the `action` parameter to `#selector(longPress)`. Currently it is all lowercase and as such is an unresolved symbol.