# how to get indexpath value uiCollectionView iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

hi I want to get the value of index path to get the data from array of the tapped cell how do I do that?

below Is my collection view method the self.iname is array that contains name and cat is category id I have to send the selected image category id to next page I am not able to extract it

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


ColCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


if(self.iname!=0){

    [cell setTag:indexPath.row];    // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later

//     add interactivity
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];

[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

   [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
 //   UITapGestureRecognizer *frameTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(frameTapGesture:)];
   // [cell.dimg addGestureRecognizer:frameTapGesture];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.iname]; //objectAtIndex:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"%@",fileName);

    NSString *baseurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/upload/"];

    NSDictionary *dict = self.iname[indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@", [self.iname objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]);

    NSString *paths = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseurl, dict];

    NSLog(@"@@@@%@",paths);

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:paths]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",response);


        UIImage *imgage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        UIImageView *dimg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
        dimg.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell.dimg setImage:imgage];


        if(cell.dimg==!nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Not nil");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"nil");
        }
        if(cell.lbl==!nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Not nil");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"nil");
        }

        cell.dimg.image=imgage;
        cell.lbl.text=[self.tempz objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.iname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    }];
}
if(cell)
{
   // self.catid=[self.categoryid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",self.catid);
}
//if (cell.selected) {
 //   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
 // }
 // else
 // {
     // cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
 // }
  return cell;
}
```

this is my tap gesture method

```
- (void)onButtonTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
  //UIImageView *myImage = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
//    do stuff;
  self.catid=self.categoryid;

  NSLog(@"%@",self.catid);
   CGPoint tapPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
  UIView *tappedView = [gestureRecognizer.view hitTest:tapPoint withEvent:nil];

  if ([tappedView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
      NSLog(@"Found");
    }
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"d2" sender:self];
  NSLog(@"it works");
 }
```

Comment: try to use model class and in collection use didselect methods it will be easier and you can pass whole object of model class in to next viewController and use it.

Comment: use didSelect method of UicollectionVIew or you can take a button in your cell from storyboard.Working with DidSelect method will be easy though.

Comment: add your gesture to that image you can direcly get the categoryid

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770240/how-to-make-tableviewcell-handle-both-tap-and-longpress/37770399#37770399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
CGPoint position = [gestureRecognizer.view convertPoint:CGPointZero
                                   toView:self.collectionView];
NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:position];
```

**OR**

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint: tapPoint];
```

Comment: It should be `indexPathForItemAtPoint`

Comment: index path is like length =2 and sth =-3

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void)onButtonTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[self.collectionView convertPoint:gestureRecognizer.view.center fromView:gestureRecognizer.view.superview]];

 NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use, UICollectionView own delegate for this?

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

As of you are adding UITapGestureRecognizer only for 1 tap gesture

Comment: but I am not able to access the particular value there

Comment: it is not executing this block

Comment: You should set owner for that delegate. self.collectionView.delegate = self;

Comment: inside which block??

Comment: -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];// highlight selection
    self.catid=[self.categoryid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"###%@",self.catid);
    
}
 I already have this block it doesn't execute this

Comment: what should I do

Comment: Add this inside viewDidLoad()

Comment: this is a method rite how ll u add this inside view did load??

Comment: I assume you have added both protocols in your class interface. @interface YouClass () <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>

Comment: Yes, you can add this in your viewDidLoad () { //some code self.collectionView.delegate = self; //some code }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146726/discussion-between-khokim-mamarasulov-and-akshay).